# How do you route an action to the application controller in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, applicationcontroller

I am using the gem rails3-jquery-autocomplete and had no problems with it, however I have now moved my autocomplete form into the application template and therefore the ajax calls are now being dealt by the application controller, so my routes have changed from:

```
home/autocomplete_category_name
```

and now need to have the home removed and the path from:

```
home_autocomplete_category_name_path
```

to:

```
autocomplete_category_name_path
```

Anybody got any ideas? Still learning the ins and outs of Rails so this is a dead end for me right now.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be best to post the current RoR actual code for the route in question as well as the URL that you are targeting.

Comment: Also, include your current routes by typing `rake routes` at the console in your root project directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

URLs don't map directly to `ApplicationController` - only subclasses of it.

You need to move the call to `autocomplete` into another controller. The location of the form shouldn't make a difference, as long as you're passing the correct path when you define your `text_field`

Comment: I have ended up doing exactly as you said, it is not an eloquent solution but it does work, thanks!

Comment: It's possible to route to ApplicationController if you want to - just against the convention of things

Comment: what if i want to set that as my root path of the application ?

Answer (score 34):

Old post, but the accepted answer is wrong. Though the spirit of it is right - you should probably move your method to a more appropriate controller; but if you *insist* on having the method in application_controller.rb

```
# routes.rb
match '/some_route', to: 'application#some_route', as: :some_route
```

...will route to the 'some_route' method in application_controller.rb.

Comment: Use `get`, `post`, etc..., instead of `match` for later versions of Rails

Answer (score 7):

Another necro but there is a more DRY friendly way to do this, compared to pavling's solution

```
get :autocomplete_category_name, controller:"application"
```

I was trying(yesterday) to move it to the Application controller to try to reuse code better and not tie it to a specific controller. Only today did I realize that makes no sense, since the controller used to answer this call is going to be a completely different object to the controller rendering the view anyway..

Comment: Works great for generic calls that are not controller-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails 4, your have to use get, not match...

```
# routes.rb
get '/autocomplete_category_name', to: 'application#autocomplete_category_name', as: :autocomplete_category_name
```

Comment: you don't *have* to... you *can* add a `via:` option.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
match "home/autocomplete_category_name", "home#autocomplete_category_name", :as => "autocomplete_category_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4, use this:

```
get 'application/autocomplete_category_name', as: 'autocomplete_category_name'
```

You have 'autocomplete_category_name_path' to you links